# Не получается вывести матрицу со смещением строк

Tags: java

Есть метод, в котором формируется матрица с заданной размерностью.

Она должна выводится в виде:

```
        1 2 3 4 5 6
        2 3 4 5 6 1
        3 4 5 6 1 2
        4 5 6 1 2 3
        5 6 1 2 3 4
        6 1 2 3 4 5
```

Код:

```
public class MatrixVer2 {

    public static int[][] Matrix2(int lenght) {

        int[][] arr = new int[lenght][lenght];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count = 1 ;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = count++;
                //System.out.print(j + " \t");
                if (count > arr.length) {
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("\n");
        }
        for (int[] res: arr) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            for (int x: res) {
                System.out.print(x + " \t");
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {


         Matrix2(5);


    }
}
```

У меня получается следующий вид:

```
0   1   2   3   4   

0   0   1   2   3   

0   0   0   1   2   

0   0   0   0   1   

0   0   0   0   0
```

Где я ошибаюсь? И есть ли более лаконичный метод (стримы)?
upd. ошибка была в счетчике
**int count = i + 1** ;
for (int **j = 0**; j < arr[i].length; j++)
как это можно написать через стримы?И можно ли эту задачу сделать через List?

Comment: что именно не нравится? не очень понятно

Comment: матрица должна выводится в том виде как в условии, у меня смещение строки происходит я видимо что то с индексами путаю

Comment: Ответ дал, сейчас напишу пояснения.

Comment: Добавил пояснения по решению, ошибки и замечания. Можно смотреть

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432588/) вы задали два дня назад, получили ответ, но не смогли им воспользоваться?

Comment: @NowhereMan, по всей видимости так и есть. Только сейчас заметил что у него есть такой же вопрос. Решения в ответах корректные. По всей видимости он испугался стримов и пр. Ну и справедливости ради: он попросил разъяснить ответ.

Comment: @MikhailBakhtin какой-то из ответов помог? Если да, то выберите наиболее подходящий поставив галочку слева от ответа. см [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

#### Замечания и пожелания

- не объявляйте методы (`Matrix2`) начинающиеся с большой буквы - это противоречит принятым в Java конвенциям
- не пытайтесь запихнуть в один метод всю реализацию. Если Ваш метод берет на себя ответственность за ряд несвязанных между собой действий - разделите его на несколько. В частности у Вас в одном методе происходит и генерация матрицы, и ее вывод. А если кто-то захочет просто сгенерировать матрицу и передать ее куда-то? Зачем лишний выхлоп в поток вывода и лишние действия?
- называйте методы в соответствии с тем, что они делают. Желательно чтобы там присутствовал глагол(  сгенерировать матрицу, распечатать матрицу и т.д.)
- старайтесь называть переменные в соответствии с их назначением. В будущем это сильно облегчит Вашу жизнь.
- если Вы производите какие-то хитрые манипцляции с данными, то можно их разделить на этапы, результат каждого из которых положив в переменную с "говорящим именем". Позже такой код будет гораздо легче читать и понимать, что у Вас там происходит. Для опытных разработчиков незазорно даже просто переложить что-то из переменной, название которой ничего не говорит в данном контексте в другую переменную, которая будет отражать её смысл и назначение при этом не производя какие-либо дополнительные манипуляций(`int salary = i;`). Все за это только скажут спасибо.

#### Ваши ошибки

Вы начинаете вложенный цикл сразу со смещением

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    // ...
}
```

Соответственно, когда вы пытаетесь что-то положить в соответствующие ячейки

```
arr[i][j] = count++;
```

вы просто пропускаете все ячейки, которые выходят за рамки данного смещения.

т.е. при `i = 2` вложенный цикл будет работать в интервале от 3 до 5 и пропускаете первые три ячейки, что мы и видем в вашем выводе:

```
0   0   0   1   2
```

#### Пояснение по моему решению

- мы проходим два вложенных цикла от 0 до указанной длины массива, не вкладывая в параметры цикла условия смещения - они тут лишние
- начало отчета внутри строки у нас равно i + 1
- смещение внутри строки у нас равно индексу вложенного цикла
- значение ячейки у нас равно

  - сумме начала отчета и смещения 
    (*если они меньше длины строки*)
  - сумме начала отчета и смещения **с вычетом длины строки**
    (*если больше*)

#### Решение

```java
public class Matrix {

    public static int[][] generateMatrix(int lenght) {
        int[][] result = new int[lenght][lenght];
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lenght; j++) {
                int start = i + 1;
                int offset = j;
                int value = start + offset;
                result[i][j] = (value <= lenght) ? value : value - lenght;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int[] row: matrix) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            for (int cellValue: row) {
                System.out.print("\t" + cellValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = generateMatrix(6);
        printMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

output:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6

    2   3   4   5   6   1

    3   4   5   6   1   2

    4   5   6   1   2   3

    5   6   1   2   3   4

    6   1   2   3   4   5
```

Answer (score 0):

> *И есть ли более лаконичный метод (стримы)?*

Такой метод можно написать, даже с выводом матрицы при помощи `Stream::peek` с учётом реализации из [прошлого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1432608/386633):

```java
    public static int[][] createFillAndPrintSquareArray(int n) {
        return IntStream.range(0, n) // поток индексов строк от 0 до n
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, n) // поток индексов колонок
                .map(j -> 1 + (i + j) % n) // значение по индексу [i][j]
                .peek(System.out::print)   // вывод значения
                .peek(j -> System.out.print('\t')) // вывод табуляции
                .toArray() // массив-строка int[]
            ) // Stream<int[]> // поток массивов-строк
            .peek(arr -> System.out.println()) // вывод новой строки
            .toArray(int[][]::new); // получить двумерный массив
    }
```

Однако, применение `Stream::peek` рекомендуется в основном для отладки, и к тому же не следует перегружать методы лишней функциональностью, как уже написал Михаил Ребров, поэтому более лаконичная реализация будет выглядеть так:

```java
    public static int[][] createAndFillSquareArray(int n) {
        return IntStream.range(0, n) // поток индексов строк от 0 до n
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, n) // поток индексов колонок
                .map(j -> 1 + (i + j) % n) // значение по индексу [i][j]
                .toArray() // массив-строка int[]
            ) // Stream<int[]> // поток массивов-строк
            .toArray(int[][]::new); // получить двумерный массив
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы немного переписал, чтобы не было путанины с индексами и нулями.

```
public class MatrixVer2 {

    public static int[][] Matrix2(int lenght) {
    
        int[][] arr = new int[lenght][lenght];
        int count = 1; // выносим вашу переменную вне циклов
        int temp = 1;  // создаем вспомогательную переменную
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = count++;
                count = (count > arr.length) ? 1 : count;
            }           
            count = ++b; 
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Большое всем спасибо за помощь!!!!